# Use RabbitMQ as procedure and Celery as consumer

Tags: python-3.x, flask, rabbitmq, celery, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm trying to use RabbitMQ, Celery, and Flask app to simply update the database. ProcedureAPI.py is an API that gets the data, inserts records in the database, and pushes data to the Radbbitmq server. Celery gets the data from Rabbit Queue and updates the database.
I'm new to this, please point out what I'm doing wrong.

consumer.py

```
from celery import Celery
import sqlite3
import time

#app = Celery('Task_Queue')
#default_config = 'celeryconfig'
#app.config_from_object(default_config)
app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://guest:guest@localhost')

@app.task(serializer='json')
def updateDB(x):
    x=x["item"]
    with sqlite3.connect("test.db") as conn:
        time.sleep(5)
        conn.execute('''updateQuery''', [x])
        # app.log(f"{x['item']} status is updated as completed!")
    return x
```

ProcedureAPI.py

```
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import json
import pika
import configparser


parser = configparser.RawConfigParser()   
configFilePath = 'appconfig.conf'
parser.read(configFilePath)

# RabbitMQ Config
rmq_username = parser.get('general', 'rmq_USERNAME')
rmq_password = parser.get('general', 'rmq_PASSWORD')
host= parser.get('general', 'rmq_IP')
port= parser.get('general', 'rmq_PORT')

# Database
DATABASE= parser.get('general', 'DATABASE_FILE')

app = Flask(__name__)
conn_credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(rmq_username, rmq_password)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host=host,
        port=port,
        credentials=conn_credentials))
channel = connection.channel()

@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_main():
   if request.method=="POST":
       print(DATABASE)
       with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE) as conn:
           conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE table1
                  (feild1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,              ##AUTOINCREMENT
                  feild2           varchar(20)    NOT NULL,
                  feild3         varchar(20)    DEFAULT 'pending');''')
           return "Table created",202

@app.route('/getData', methods=['GET'])
def display_main():
   if request.method=="GET":
       with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE) as conn:
           df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from table1", conn)
           df_list = df.values.tolist()
           JSONP_data = jsonify(df_list)
           return JSONP_data,200

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def update_main():
    if request.method=="POST":
       updatedata=request.get_json()
       with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE) as conn:
           conn.execute("INSERT_Query")
           print("Records Inserted successfully")
           channel.queue_declare(queue='celery', durable=True)
           channel.basic_publish(exchange = 'celery',routing_key ='celery' ,body = json.dumps(updatedata),properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode = 2))
           return updatedata,202

# main driver function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

configfile

```
[general]

# RabbitMQ server (broker) IP address
rmq_IP=127.0.0.1

# RabbitMQ server (broker) TCP port number (5672 or 5671 for SSL)
rmq_PORT=5672

# queue name (storage node hostname)
rmq_QUEUENAME=Task_Queue

# RabbitMQ authentication
rmq_USERNAME=guest
rmq_PASSWORD=guest


DATABASE_FILE=test.db
# log file
receiver_LOG_FILE=cmdmq_receiver.log
sender_LOG_FILE=cmdmq_sender.log
```

run celery

```
celery -A consumer worker --pool=solo -l info
```

The error I got:

```
(env1) PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Desktop\Jobs Search\nodepython\flaskapp> celery -A consumer worker --pool=solo -l info
 
 -------------- celery@DESKTOP-FRBNH77 v5.2.0 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0 2021-11-12 17:35:04
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x1ec10c9c5c8
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     rpc://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (solo)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . consumer.updateDB

[2021-11-12 17:35:04,546: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//      
[2021-11-12 17:35:04,571: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2021-11-12 17:35:05,594: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2021-11-12 17:35:05,605: INFO/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-FRBNH77 ready.
[2021-11-12 17:35:14,952: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: '{"item": "1BOOK"}' (17b)
{content_type:None content_encoding:None
  delivery_info:{'consumer_tag': 'None4', 'delivery_tag': 1, 'redelivered': False, 'exchange': 
'celery', 'routing_key': 'celery'} headers={}}
```

Any reference code or suggestion will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven’t declare the exchange and bind into queue that you want to route

```py
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='exchange_name', exchange_type="type_of_exchange")

channel.queue_bind(exchange='exchange_name, queue='your queue_name')
```

- Producer : P
- Exchange : E
- Queue : Q
- Bind : B

Producer(your pika script) does not able to send message directly Producer needs some intermediate to send to Queue, therefore message route from

P >> E >> B >> Q

Exchange route the request to one or multiple Queue depending upon exchange type

Bind (As name explain) it use to bind the exchanges to Queue depending upon exchange type

for more detail please refer ::
https://hevodata.com/learn/rabbitmq-exchange-type/